# Using JQuery, how can I display a CSS change as it's being made?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to JQuery and trying to figure out how to do this properly.

I have a web form with a drop down and multiple input fields.  As the user makes a selection and enters text I am able to display the text the user has entered but I have two things I can't figure out:

1) In one of the input fields, a user can enter the height of a button.  What I want to do is take the value (i.e: 300px or 300) and then make that change real time to show them what it would look like

2)  There is a drop down that they can select an option from.  I just want to show that selection in a span

This is what I have so far:

```
$('#some_button').keyup(function () {
      $('#some_text_is').text($(this).val());
      });
```

This will show text inputted into an input field but how can I do something for #1 and #2.

Comment: `$('#some_text_is').height($(this).val());`?

Comment: @dfsq but i think it will not work on real time basis

Comment: @Prashant It will be as real-time as the JavaScript code "yields".

Comment: @dfsq you are right! thanks! so i can continue to do this for other css properties? Like box-shadow, etc too?

Comment: To use it with other css properties you need to use the css function, but yes, it will work the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dfsq is right, each time you release a key in your keyboard it should change the styling of the button immediately. 
For the second question, I'm not quite sure I understood what you want to do with the value. 
you can get the value by fetching the element with jquery, and then using the val function like so

```
$('#some-dropdown').val()
```

You can then put this value into any html element you want.

Comment: Thanks! For #2 I want to show the selection in a span tag.

Comment: So you can just fetch it using jquery as you normally would and then using the html function put the dropdown value inside $('#mySpan').html($('#some-dropdown').val());

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try that.  However, using the approach by dfsq, I am unable to change the background-color, I am doing this: $('#test_button').backgroundColor($(this).val());

Comment: See my answer on the OP. You need to use the css function like so $('#test_button').css('background-color',$(this).val()

Comment: Thanks so much! This was so helpful to me.

Comment: i am trying to use this to change the hover color for links using this: $("#hover_field").on("mouseover", function () {
      $('a').css('color', $(this).val());
      }); but it's not working and no console error.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What value is inside the $(this).val()? Are you sure it's a valid css value?

Answer (score 0):

1. for 1st case you can use `height()`

> ```
> $('#some_button').keyup(function () {
>        var height = $(this).val();
>       $('#some_text_is').height(height);
>   });
> ```

2. For second case you can use `change()`

> $('#some_dropdown').change(function () {
>
> ```
>      $('#some_text_is').text($(this).val());
> });
> ```